# How to handle the same key differently depending on source keyboard?

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard

**Background**

I have a laptop (a Thinkpad P15) that came with a stylus for the touch screen. I'm trying to get this to work under Linux.

The stylus has three buttons, and shows up as three devices: two Wacom devices (stylus and eraser) handle two of the buttons, depending on how they are pressed. The third button is different though, and shows up as a bluetooth keyboard. This button can be used even when the stylus is not next to the screen.

**Problem**

The problem is that this fake key press from the stylus uses a key code that is shared with a media button on my main USB keyboard (`198` in both cases). I'd like to bind the key to do different things depending on if it comes from the pen (advance slides in a presentation would be nice for example) and on my USB keyboard (where it is currently bound using AutoKey to run a script).

Using `xinput test` I can tell the sources apart, but I don't know of a program that can bind keys differently depending on the source. AutoKey doesn't seem to be able to do it. Maybe one of the keys can simply be remapped at some low level to a different key which doesn't collide?

I need the solution for X.Org, not Wayland (for now I'm stuck with nvidia drivers), though if you want to add a bonus solution for Wayland, go for it).